# "class template has already been declared as a non-class template"

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces, compiler-errors

Hey i'm getting this **odd error when I leave the `namespace sf{`** declaration in the later code:

```
1>c:\libraries and headers\sfml\sfml-1.6-sdk-windows-vc2008\sfml-1.6\include\sfml\graphics\body.h(70): error C2989: 'sf::Body' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template
1>c:\libraries and headers\sfml\sfml-1.6-sdk-windows-vc2008\sfml-1.6\include\sfml\graphics\body.h(11): error C3856: 'sf': class is not a class template
```

The code worked fine when it wasn't a template class for the past 3 weeks, With the same sf::Body class name; i just recently changed it to make it more flexible. Can i not declare a template class inside a namespace or what?

**Here's the code:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

namespace sf{ //when i take this out and the closing bracket the code runs fine

    template<typename drawable>     
class Body : public sf::Drawable{ 

    private:
        sf::Vector2f MoveVal;
        std::vector<drawable> Drawables;

    public:
        Body(const Vector2f& Position = Vector2f(0, 0), const Vector2f& Scale = Vector2f(1, 1), float Rotation = 0.f, const Color& Col = Color(255, 255, 255, 255)){
            SetPosition(Position);
            SetScale(Scale);
            SetRotation(Rotation);
            SetColor(Col);};

// Overide Drawable Functions To Detect any Movement
        void SetX(float X){
            MoveVal.x += X - GetPosition().x;
            Drawable::SetX(X);};

        void SetY(float Y){
            MoveVal.y += Y - GetPosition().y;
            Drawable::SetY(Y);};

// Regular Functions
        void AddObject(drawable& Object){
            Object.Move(GetX(),GetY());
            Drawables.push_back(Object);};

        void DestroyObject(unsigned short Index){
            Drawables.erase(Drawables.begin()+Index);};

        void Clear(){
            Drawables.clear();};

        drawable& GetObject(unsigned short index) 
            {return Drawables[index];};

        unsigned int GetNumbObjects() 
        {return Drawables.size();};

        void Draw(sf::RenderTarget& target){
            for(unsigned short I=0; I<Drawables.size(); I++){
                //Body offset
                Drawables[I].SetPosition( 
                    Drawables[I].GetPosition().x + MoveVal.x,
                    Drawables[I].GetPosition().y + MoveVal.y);
            }                                                   // TODO: add tint based on overall Body Color

            target.Draw(*this); 

            //Reset all the Change Values
            MoveVal.x=0;
            MoveVal.y=0;
        };

        void Render(sf::RenderTarget& target) const{
            for(int I=0; I< Drawables.size(); I++)
                Drawables[I].Draw(target);
        };
};// Body Class

} //namespace sf
```

Comment: +1 Interesting. However you don't need `;` after function body.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd put a clear comment in the source so we know which lines those errors are reported at... painful to count or hunt or cut-paste-jump just to begin investigating your problem.  Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I've picked up that habit from "Sam's C++"

Comment: Just a guess, but does the header file `<SFML/Graphics.hpp>` define a (non-template) class named `Body` in the `sf` namespace?

Comment: @Tony: You mean add a comment next namespace sf{ ? Done!

Comment: @Griffin - actually, I meant put a comment saying "// LINE 70 -  ERROR HERE"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two most likely candidates based on your information are that `Graphics.hpp` has mismatched `{` `}` or that you had a forward declaration of `class Body` without marking it a template.

Comment: @Griffin: If it used to not be a template, that would certainly be an argument in favor of "a forward declaration of `class Body` without marking it a template."

Comment: I found the problem: i declared Body to be friend of a previous class, without designating it as a template.

Answer (score 11):

Ok found the problem:

In a previously included header file: **Shape.hpp** I declare `Body` as a friend with the following syntax:

```
friend class Body;
```

Which apparently makes the compiler assume Body is not a template (no template indication is made)
The correct syntax was:

```
template <typename drawable>    
friend class Body;
```

Because now the compiler understands Body as a template class

Comment: While this answer is correct, you should accept one of the others. They are telling you exactly the same thing even if you did not understand what they meant and kept complaining that **this** could not be the issue.

Comment: guess i didn't understand this to be an actual declaration of a class rather than just a friend declaration, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

`sf::Body` is a name that seems to be already taken (for a class whereas you're declaring a template). Are you sure you want to put your code in the `sf` namespace? It's more customary to use one's own namespaces rather than those of the libraries they use.

Comment: The code worked fine when it wasn't a template class for the past 3 weeks, With the same sf::Body class name. So i don't think it's a double declaration problem...

Comment: @Griffin: `typedef int X; typedef int X;` is perfectly valid C++, then you go and change it to `typedef int X; typedef double X;` and you get an error. The argument: *it worked when it was different* does not hold here: it is because it is different now, that the double declaration is triggering the error.